# solr join on multiple cores in solr 4.6.1

Tags: join, solr

I'm trying to write a join query between two solr cores that are on the same jvm. A very simple description of the cores: **categories** containing id (int field) and keywords (multivalued text field) and **firma** containing information about companies whit one field categ_id (multivalued int field). What I'm trying to get is the id's of the companies that have the searched keyword, but first I just want to see all companies from a given category by id. The query look like that:

`catDEkw/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&fl=*,score&fq={!join from=id to=cf_cs_ids fromIndex=searchDEbis}cf_cs_ids:926`

where:

- catDEkw is the categories core whit id as categories id
- searchDEbis is the core that contains info about companies and have the cf_cs_ids field (which is a multivalued field)

No results. Am I doing something wrong? Or the problem is the field type after the join was made?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but if I understand correctly, the from should be cf_cs_ids. i.e;

> catDEkw/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&fl=*,score&fq={!join
>   **from=cf_cs_ids to=id** fromIndex=searchDEbis}cf_cs_ids:926

Comment: Well, frankly, I miss the logic, but you're right! Thank you very much and have a nice day!